# Jquery Toggle Jitter weird animation

Tags: jquery, toggle, togglebutton

ive been searching for quite a while BUT I can't quite find any similar problems to what I have.

I have deployed my website in http://91.121.167.76/bpm2/, and I have created a block that has `position: fixed;` style and is at the right side of the website, now I used jQuery to show/hide its content,

```
$(".toggle_button").click(function(){
    $(".content").toggle("slow");
});
```

the mark up looks like this,

```
<div class="fixed_block">
    <div class="toggle_button" >Message</div>
    <div class="content clearfix ui segment">
        "form here"
    </div>
</div>
```

when it shows up, it looks like it have some recoil animation, ( i dunno what to call), i removed initial styles (margin, padding) but to no luck, I cant fix it.

Please see the website to understand better the weird animation i am telling,

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: A few questions and remarks : are you talking about "#region-footer-third"? `$` is not defined on your site? Wow, 47 scripts loaded??  I can't find any "toggle_button" in your DOM (`document.getElementsByClassName("toggle_button")` is empty), but `document.getElementsByClassName("content")` finds 4 different divs...

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorry this is the exact selector i used, `#region-footer-third .block-webform .feedback_message` and this is the one in toggle `#region-footer-third .block-webform .content`

Comment: Ok I got it! The "weird animation" appears because the text changes inside your button when it expand or contracts. At the very last frame of your animation, "Hide" becomes "Message". Since the word is longer, the button suddenly becomes wider and "jumps" to the left. My advice would be, don't wait for the very last frame to switch the words, do it in the middle of the animation, when everything is in movement.

Comment: thank you for the reply, though, I suspected that also, so I tried removing it but the weird flicker still exist. for the meantime i just added maxheight for the container to lessen the flicker but if you look closely, the flicker is still there..

Comment: ok I GOTIT!! GRR hahaha its because of the text description below the textboxes, because when the width is too small, the descriptions are in two lines,, increasing the height of the container, and when the width is enough, the description becomes one line, thus creating the flicker effect!! thanks for your comments! :)